# ApexCharts onclick event for labels

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apexcharts

Is there any way to add clickEvent Handler to the labels of timeline chart in React.

Link to Chart: https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/timeline-charts/advanced/

For DataPoints, there is dataPointSelection event, But I want to attach a event handler when user clicks on labels.

Comment: I already posted an answer about a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74230539/add-hyperlink-in-the-yaxis-of-apexcharthorizontal-bar-chart-vuejs-javascript/75024767#75024767