# Add hyperlink in the yaxis of ApexChart(horizontal bar chart) vuejs javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bar-chart, apexcharts

I am using apexchart to visualize the data and I am having an issue with adding a hyperlink or link to yaxis data as I need to go navigate to another page when clicking the yaxis data.
Here is the code that I used,

```
      yaxis: {
        tickAmount: 4,
        enabled: true,
        labels: {
          formatter: function(value, timestamp, opts) {
            return '<a href="' + value+ '">' +
                value + '</a>';
          },
          style: {
            colors: "#000000",
            fontSize: "10px",
            opacity: "0.6"
          }
        },
      },
```

The results is not I expected.
[image]

Anyone here to help me out to get this work.

Comment: It seems right now ApexChart axis Formatter returns only type string | string []. Looks like there is open issue for the same https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts/issues/390

Answer (score 0):

Technically, since ApexCharts is based on SVG, you can do what you want if you manipulate the DOM yourself. **Be aware, though, that what I am going to show you here is more experimental than official.** Use the code at your own risk!

To get clickable labels, we can:

1. put an `onclick` attribute on the selected `<text>` elements (`.apexcharts-yaxis-label`);
2. change `window.location.href` after a `switch` which determines the right URL;
3. use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes in the SVG structure.

### 1. `onclick`

```js
function setLinks() {
  let labels = document.querySelectorAll('.apexcharts-yaxis-label');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].setAttribute('onclick', `goTo(${i})`);
  }
}
```

### 2. `window.location.href`

```js
function goTo(index) {
  let url = '';
  
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      url = 'https://apexcharts.com/';
      break;
    case 1:
      url = 'https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js';
      break;
    case 2:
      url = 'https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/apexcharts';
      break;
  }
  
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

### 3. `MutationObserver`

```js
const chartDiv = document.querySelector('#chart');
```

```js
chart: {
  height: 350,
  type: 'bar',
  events: {
    mounted: () => {
      let settings = { childList: true },
          observer = new MutationObserver(() => setLinks());

      observer.observe(chartDiv, settings);
      setLinks();
    }
  }
},
```

Here is the final result (where I put a `console.log` instead of `window.location.href`):

```js
function goTo(index) {
  let url = '';
  
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      url = 'https://apexcharts.com/';
      break;
    case 1:
      url = 'https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js';
      break;
    case 2:
      url = 'https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/apexcharts';
      break;
  }
  
  // window.location.href = url;
  console.log(url);
}

function setLinks() {
  let labels = document.querySelectorAll('.apexcharts-yaxis-label');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].setAttribute('onclick', `goTo(${i})`);
  }
}

const chartDiv = document.querySelector('#chart');

let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      mounted: () => {
        let settings = { childList: true },
            observer = new MutationObserver(() => setLinks());

        observer.observe(chartDiv, settings);
        setLinks();
      }
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['Website', 'GitHub', 'jsDelivr']
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true
    }
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(chartDiv, options);
chart.render();
```

```css
.apexcharts-yaxis-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: This appears to lead to "goTo is not defined", at least in React.